# Can I use typecasting functions inside group by clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I want to GROUP my records on the basis of `LogInDate` column. Data type of `LogInDate` is `datetime` but I want to use `GROUP BY` with only date of this field and don't want to include time.

**Here is what I have tried to get unique Login counts of last 7 days**

```
select LogInDate,count(*)
    from Login
    group by  LogInDate,UserID
    having LogInDate< (getdate() - 6);
```

But it groups on the basis of both date and time of `LogInDate` value. I have tried to use `CONVERT` inside `GROUP BY` as following

```
select LogInDate,count(*)
    from Login
    group by CONVERT(date,LogInDate) ,UserID
    having LogInDate< (getdate() - 6);
```

**but then it failed saying :**

> Msg 8121, Level 16, State 1, Line 17 Column 'Login.LogInDate' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `having` you need to use aggregation like this

`having max(CONVERT(date,LogInDate))>= (getdate() - 6)`

But in  your case it can be done by `where clause` like below -

```
    select CONVERT(date,LogInDate),count(*)
        from Login where LogInDate< (getdate() - 6)
        group by CONVERT(date,LogInDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have put sample data below for your reference.

```
CREATE TABLE #LoginValues(LoginDate datetime, UserID int)
INSERT INTO #LoginValues
values ('2019-01-28', 2), ('2019-01-29', 1),('2019-01-22', 3),('2019-01-28', 3);

DECLARE @Filterdate DATE = DATEADD(dd,-6,getdate())
;WITH CTE_LoginDate
AS
(
select cast(LogInDate as Date) AS LoginDate,UserID
    from #LoginValues
    WHERE LoginDate > @Filterdate
)
SELECT LoginDate, COUNT(*)
from cte_loginDate
group by LoginDate
```